# Simulink non-tunable variable as a macro/constant in C/C++ code

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink

I defined a constant parameter in Simulink, that is used inside a Matlab function block to create a fixed-size buffer. This parameter is a variable in the workspace.

In order to generate the equivalent C/C++ code, Simulink requires to set the variable as "Inlined" so that it is identified as non-tunable. The result is that the literal value (lets say, 200) is harcoded in several places of the code.

I would like to have it defined as a macro in the resulting C code, so that the buffer size can be changed from a single point without having to regenerate code from the Simulink model. 
In `Configuration Parameters -> Code generation -> Symbols`, you can find the option "Generate scalar inlined parameters as:" set to value "Macros". However, this does not help.

Do somebody know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a function that has the number hard coded in it can help you.

Just make a function that gives 200 on the output and call it all the time you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't missinterpret it, it is not what I'm looking for. I have rewritten the question to make it clearer: we have a MATLAB file where all tunable and non-tunable variables are defined. But my goal is to generate a C code where both tunable and non-tunable variables can be modified from a single point. For the latter, I like to have C macros instead of the harcoded value spread over the code. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: The thing is that Matlab don't have `#define` equivalent. This is maybe the only way to workaround that disability of Matlab.

Maybe I am not getting it right, but I believe that with an external function that just gives back the variable written inside, you can fix this. You just have to call the function every time you need the variable.
For example:
`temp_var=get_var_value();`

You can even have some `if` functions inside with which you can change the value of the variable, by using maybe `varargin` and `varargout`.

Comment: Or, there is another possible way, and that's by using a global variable. You define it in the beginning and use it in all of your functions as a fixed variable.
That's all I know. I hope I helped you.
If not, good luck with your solution :)